# How to prevent ckeditor not saving HTML tags, but just the rich text

Tags: html, model-view-controller, text, ckeditor

Please find attached the html code  and the printscreen of my problem . When i write something in ckeditor , and apply styling with html tags , it saved the text with html tags , and not just the text itself , in this case just **`CONTENT SAMPLE TEXT`**, and to apply the styling for html certain tags , and not show

<p></p>

Result:

[image]

```
  <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LongDescription1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">

           @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.LongDescription1, new { @id = "LongDescription1", @class = "form-control", @rows = "200" })



            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LongDescription1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <script>CKEDITOR.replace("LongDescription1", { htmlEncodeOutput: true });</script>


        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I am working with Visual Studio .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML code is escaped. You will need to unescape it before displaying.

You can do that with PHP using

```
$string = '&lt;div&gt;SAMPLE TEXT&lt;/div&gt;' ;
$string = html_entity_decode($string) ;
echo $string;
```

output

```
SAMPLE TEXT
```

in the right div

Comment: Thanks but its not something i asked for . I work with asp.net mvc and it should have a way to automatically convert just the rich text